# mySQL : How to use a PDO bound paramter within a CASE statement of SELECT query ?

Tags: mysql

In a mySQL `SELECT` query I want to select rows of a client table based upon a PDO bound search parameter condition in a WHERE clause. Something like `WHERE client = :searchStr`

There are 2 cases : 
A) a search parameter contains a string or
B) the search parameter is empty

In the case of A the param `:searchStr` contains for instance a client number '123'.

So I use :  `WHERE client = :searchStr` and the query return client 123 if the client is in the table.

In the case of B the string is empty. So I do not use a WHERE clause and the query simply returns all clients  in the table

Of course I could write an IF ..  ELSE statement outside the SELECT query.
But how to code it with a CASE statement inside the SELECT query ?

Something like

```
CASE   
   WHEN :searchStr = '' THEN WHERE client = :searchStr
END
```

does not work

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE (:searchStr = '' or client = :searchStr)
```

or if `:searchStr` can be NULL and not just an emprty string use

```
WHERE (:searchStr is null or client = :searchStr)
```

Comment: this answer seems perfect because I do not need a CASE statement at all. But NULL is not working because in my case the searchStr is always initialized and just empty. Because I use a PDO prepare statment with a string I need to use double qoutes instead of single quotes.